# TPL execute Dependent task and stop all task when some task fails

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a list of task and few task are dependent on others, I would like to run the tasks now and if any of the task fails during execution, need to stop all the running task and close the application.

How can do this with TPL?
How to stop the running task?
I need to optimize the below code.

Detailed Requirement
-   Start the Logon screen as a task. 
o   Run all other task in parallel only if the Logon is successful.
o   Exit application in case of Logon failure or Cancel
-   Exit application if any of the task fails

```
        var done = new List<TaskDetails>();
        var executing = new List<TaskDetails>();
        var unblocked = new List<TaskDetails>();
        var blocked = new List<TaskDetails>();
        foreach (var startupTest in startupTests) {
            if (startupTest.DependsOn == null) {
                unblocked.Add(startupTest);
            } else {
                blocked.Add(startupTest);
            }
        }

        IDictionary<int, TaskDetails> tasksByID = new Dictionary<int, TaskDetails>();
        var tasksTPL = new Task<object>[startupTests.Count];
        var taskCount = 0;
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        while (done.Count < startupTests.Count) {
            while (executing.Count < config.MaximumConcurrency && unblocked.Count > 0) {
                TaskDetails nextTask = unblocked[0];
                lock (syncLock) {
                    unblocked.Remove(nextTask);
                    executing.Add(nextTask);
                }
                // Execute
                try {
                    var method = GetMethod(
                        nextTask.AssemblyName, nextTask.ClassName, nextTask.MethodName
                    );
                    if (method == null) {
                        throw new Exception("Method" + nextTask.MethodName + " not available.");
                    }
                    tasksTPL[taskCount] = 
                        Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() => method.Invoke(null, null), 
                        cancellationToken);
                    tasksByID.Add(tasksTPL[taskCount].Id, nextTask);
                    tasksTPL[taskCount].ContinueWith(tsk => {
                        lock (syncLock) {
                            done.Add(tasksByID[tsk.Id]);
                            executing.Remove(tasksByID[tsk.Id]);
                        }
                        if (tsk.Exception != null) {
                            TraceAlways(
                                "Caught Exception while running startuptest: " +
                                tsk.Exception
                            );
                        }
                    });
                    taskCount++;
                } catch (TargetInvocationException e) {
                    TraceAlways(
                        "Failed running " + nextTask.MethodName + " method." + e.Message);
                }
            }
            Task.WaitAny(tasksTPL.Where(task => task != null).ToArray());
            var toRemove = new List<TaskDetails>();
            lock (syncLock) {
                List<string> doneTaskName = 
                    done.Select(TaskDetails => TaskDetails.Name).ToList();
                foreach (var task in blocked) {
                    bool isBlocked = task.DependsOn.Any(dep => !doneTaskName.Contains(dep));
                    if (!isBlocked) {
                        toRemove.Add(task);
                        unblocked.Add(task);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var TaskDetails in toRemove) {
                    blocked.Remove(TaskDetails);
                }
            }
            if (executing.Count == 0 && unblocked.Count == 0 && blocked.Count > 0) {
                throw new Exception("Cyclic Dependency");
            }
        }
        taskCount = 0;
        foreach (var task in tasksTPL) {
            if (
                (task.Status != TaskStatus.Faulted) && 
                (task.Result is bool) && 
                (!(bool)task.Result)
            ) {
                TraceAlways("Startup Test" + startupTests[taskCount].MethodName + " failed.");
                if (startupTests[taskCount].ShowNotification) {
                    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                    MessageBox.Show(
                        "An error has accoured. See log for more details.", "Startup Error"
                    );
                }
                Environment.Exit(0);
                break;
            }
            taskCount++;
        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify your requirement? First you say you'd like to run all tasks optimistically and cancel them if another one failed. You later say you want to only run the dependent tasks if the first one fails.

Answer (score 2):

Below is how I would implement it conceptually (if I understood the question correctly), although I did not attempt to meet all of your detailed requirements.

- The code doesn't use `ContinueWith`.
- `DoTaskAsync` is an individual independent task.
- `DoTaskSequenceAsync` is a sequence of tasks, where some tasks depend on the result of the others.
- `BadTaskAsync` is an example of the throwing tasks, its failure should cancel all other pending tasks.
- `WrapAsync` wraps a task with `try/catch` to catch the task's exceptions and raise the global cancellation from inside.
- All tasks also support the global cancellation from outside.

You can compile and try it as a console app.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MultipleTasks
{
    class Program
    {
        class Worker
        {
            // a single async Task
            async Task<object> DoTaskAsync(string id, CancellationToken token, int delay)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task: " + id);
                await Task.Delay(delay, token); // do some work
                return id;
            }

            // DoTaskSequenceAsync depends on Task1, Task2, Task3
            async Task<object> DoTaskSequenceAsync(string id, CancellationToken token)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task: " + id);
                await DoTaskAsync(id + "." + "Task1", token, 1000);
                await DoTaskAsync(id + "." + "Task2", token, 2000);
                await DoTaskAsync(id + "." + "Task3", token, 3000);
                // do more
                return id;
            }

            // a bad task which throws 
            async Task<object> BadTaskAsync(string id, CancellationToken token, int delay)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task: " + id);
                await Task.Delay(delay, token);
                throw new ApplicationException(id);
            }

            // wraps a task and requests the cancellation if the task has failed 
            async Task<T> WrapAsync<T>(CancellationTokenSource cts,
                Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>> taskFactory)
            {
                try
                {
                    return await taskFactory(cts.Token);
                }
                catch
                {
                    if (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        cts.Cancel(); // cancel the others
                    }
                    throw; // rethrow
                }
            }

            // run all tasks
            public async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken outsideCt)
            {
                var tasks = new List<Task<object>>();

                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

                ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException = null;

                try
                {
                    using (outsideCt.Register(() => cts.Cancel()))
                    {
                        // these tasks run in parallel
                        tasks.Add(WrapAsync(cts, (token) => DoTaskAsync("Task1", token, 500)));
                        tasks.Add(WrapAsync(cts, (token) => DoTaskSequenceAsync("Sequence1", token)));
                        tasks.Add(WrapAsync(cts, (token) => DoTaskAsync("Task2", token, 1000)));
                        tasks.Add(WrapAsync(cts, (token) => BadTaskAsync("BadTask", token, 1200)));
                        tasks.Add(WrapAsync(cts, (token) => DoTaskSequenceAsync("Sequence2", token)));
                        tasks.Add(WrapAsync(cts, (token) => DoTaskAsync("Task3", token, 1500)));

                        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    capturedException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(e);
                }

                if (outsideCt.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cancelled from outside.");
                    return;
                }

                if (cts.IsCancellationRequested || capturedException != null)
                {
                    if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled by a failed task.");
                        // find the failed task in tasks or via capturedException
                    }
                    if (capturedException != null && capturedException.SourceException != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Source exception: " + capturedException.SourceException.ToString());
                        // could rethrow the original exception:
                        // capturedException.Throw();                   
                    }   
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Results:");
                tasks.ForEach((task) =>
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Status: {0}, result: {1}",
                            task.Status.ToString(), 
                            task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion? task.Result.ToString(): String.Empty)));
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(10000);
            new Worker().DoWorkAsync(cts.Token).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```